# HTML5+CSS3 Framework like BluePrint/960gs?

Tags: html, frameworks, css

I'm starting a side project and want to build it with HTML5+CSS3. Backward compatibility isn't a concern.

I wonder if exist a framework similar to BluePrint/960gs. Mainly, I'm looking for the grid system & typography. The best (and only) I found that plays nice with the new HTML5 tags is [Less Framework](http://lessframework.com/), it's a good start but I wonder if something better exists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think http://52framework.com/ its better!

Comment: 52framework is great, just released version 2.0 that has a lot of amazing improvements and new features!

Answer (score 4):

Try [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/).

Comment: Looks cool to me. I also couldn't see a 24 column option for 52Frameworks (site:52framework.com/ 24 column = 0 results), whereas I should be able to update some of my 960.gs sites by engineering a solution using Susy/Sass.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason you can't use an existing CSS framework with CSS3 properties; CSS3 is not backwards-incompatible.

Comment: Actually those existing ones don't have great support for HTML5 being backward compatible, so starting off with 52framework or eve Less is a better choice!